# How to build library OpenFace using jhbuild without cmake file?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, gnome, jhbuild

**I want to build OpenFace library in my project, but facing some issues.**

**What I have done:**

- I have cloned OpenFace library from github and put into jhbuild.
- I have created `openface.moduleset` file to build the library in my project, but OpenFace don't have a `CMakeLists.txt` file. So I'm unable to understand what I have to write in `.moduleset file` to build OpenFace library.
- I have built OpenFace library using `sudo apt-get`, followed all command they provide in thair website, built without `jhbuild`, but using `jhbuild` I am stuck how can i do it :(.

**Problem:**

- In OpenFace library there is no cmake file.
- I have made a `.moduleset` file, but how to build OpenFace if the library doesn't provide cmake support, so how can I do it using `sudo apt` with `jhbuild`.
- What I have to write in `.moduleset` file to build library in project using `jhbuild`?

Please help !!

Comment: @wasthishelpful - Thank you for making question understandable, Sorry I am new at stack overflow but next time i will try my best to present more understandable question.

Comment: Please provide reason why you gave negative vote for this question because it is very serious issue for me and if any mistake in  question than i can modified it, please write comment here before make it negative, help appreciated.

Comment: Your question is very specific. It might be your problem, but it will not help anybody beside you. And there is not specific question, we would need to follow your steps and write the code for you. That's not how SO works.

Comment: @usr1234567 - You are right but what is the solution of openface library dosn't having cmake file so how can i build that library using jhbuild, please provide any idea, I need to do it any how so and i am not asking that follow my steps and give me solution but i just ask, Is there any way to build library without cmake using jhbuild? thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about this OpenFace library: http://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/

If so, then it is a Python library, built/installed with Distutils.

That's why you can't find a `CMakeLists.txt` file: OpenFace does not use CMake to build.

Fortunately, JHBuild is not tied to CMake at all, and it supports Distutils just fine:

https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/stable/moduleset-syntax.html.en#moduleset-syntax-defs-distutils

So you would just add something like this to your moduleset file:

```
<moduleset>
  ...

  <repository type="tarball" name="tarball.github.com" href="https://github.com/" />

  ...

  <distutils id="OpenFace">
    <branch repo="tarball.github.com"
            module="cmusatyalab/openface/archive/{version}.tar.gz"
            version="0.2.1"
            hash="sha256:ee7bfbd16a00aec05636db5c5a38b45b7cc2a3a421860ad8c4dbc99842892942"
            checkoutdir="openface-${version}">
    </branch>
    <dependencies>
      ...
    </dependencies>
  </distutils>

  ...
</moduleset>
```